# How to use EWS to retrieve mail-related information about Exchange mail-enabled public folders

Tags: c#, powershell, exchangewebservices

Using PowerShell I can call Get-MailPublicFolder to retrieve mail-related information about Exchange mail-enabled public folders.

I want to do the same thing using EWS. And in particular get the Public Folder Email Addresses.

So far I've managed to get the Public Folders as a list of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder objects. But I can't see a property on the Folder object that returns the Folder Email Addresses. And I've checked the ExtendedProperties property and it's an empty list.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

// Use Autodiscover to set the URL endpoint.
service.AutodiscoverUrl("joe.bloggs@microsoft.com");

Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot);
FolderView folderView = new FolderView(1000);

foreach (Folder folder in rootfolder.FindFolders(folderView))
{
    folder.Load();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Folder Name: " + folder.DisplayName);

    if (folder.ExtendedProperties.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ExtendedProperty ep in folder.ExtendedProperties)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" " + ep.PropertyDefinition.Name + " = " + ep.Value);
        }
    }                    
}
```

Can someone please show me an example on how to do it using EWS?

Thank you

### **UPDATE**

I've converted the code Shay posted into C#, and it works :)

Here is the code converted into C#:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

// Use Autodiscover to set the URL endpoint.
service.AutodiscoverUrl("joe.bloggs@microsoft.com");

Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot);

FolderView folderView = new FolderView(1000);
ExtendedPropertyDefinition proxyProp = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(26397, MapiPropertyType.Binary);
folderView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(proxyProp);

foreach (Folder folder in rootfolder.FindFolders(folderView))
{
    object objectGuid;
    if (folder.TryGetProperty(proxyProp, out objectGuid))
    {
        objectGuid = System.BitConverter.ToString((byte[])objectGuid).Replace("-", "");
        var adFolder = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://<GUID={0}>", objectGuid.ToString()));
        var mailVal = adFolder.Properties["Mail"].Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reference to any MS docs out there that can provide more details on the tag 26397?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm able to get it with the following, you'll need to translate it to c#. The result is a folder object extended with an Email property.

```
$PR_PF_PROXY = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition 26397,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Binary
$view.PropertySet.Add($PR_PF_PROXY) 

$foldersResult = $ExchangeService.FindFolders(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::PublicFoldersRoot,$view)

    foreach($folder in $foldersResult.Folders)
    {  
        $folder = $folder | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Email -Value $null -PassThru

        $guid=$null
        if($folder.TryGetProperty($PR_PF_PROXY,[ref]$guid))
        {
            $dn=[bitconverter]::ToString($guid) -replace '-'
            $folder.Email = ([ADSI]"LDAP://<GUID=$dn>").Properties.mail.value
        }

        $folder
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Shay. I converted your code into C# and it works. I'll post the C# code in my original post.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the tag: 26397? I'd like to know if this will be supported in all versions of exchange/office365